# Logical union of groups

Tags: group-theory, notation

I need to denote the state of a physical systems which is invariant under the action of either the group $A$ or the group $B$ (or both). Would it be appropriate to denote that invariance by $A\vee B$ using the logical conjunction symbol "$\vee$"? Is there any other more appropriate symbol?

CLARIFICATION: It is just a question about notation. Suppose we have different configurations of "balls" in a plane. Some of these satisfy certain symmetries, for example if we have 4 balls in a square configuration, that configuration presents $D_4$ symmetry. Suppose that "only the configurations which invariant under the action of either the subgroup $A$ or the subgroup $B$ can be considered". Is there any compact mathematical notation to rewrite in elegant form the sentence between quotation marks ($A\vee B$-Symmetry?, $\{A,B\}$-Symmetry)?

Comment: What do you mean with a situation?

Comment: For example, a particular state of a physical system

Comment: I would give more context, or people will down vote your question. Maybe by explicitely describing what that invariance is.

Comment: It is an invariance under some particular planar rotations or reflections, A contains some of them and the identity, and B contains others the the identity.

Comment: What do you mean by both?

Comment: @JJR, I mean "invariant under both groups of symmetries"

Comment: Perhaps a solution is to say invariance under the set (of sets) $\{A,B\}$

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you mean:

We have some space $X$ of 'configurations' and a group action $G \times X \to X$. There is a subset of configurations $Y \subset X$ which is invariant under the two subgroups $A,B \subset G$. That means every $a \cdot y=y$ and $b \cdot y = y$ for $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ and $y \in Y$.

To answer your question, there always exists a minimal subgroup of $G$ containing both $A$ and $B$. This subgroup is denoted by $\langle A,B\rangle$ and can be constructed as the set of all elements $g_1^{\pm1} \cdot g_2^{\pm1} \cdot \ldots \cdot g_N^{\pm1}$ for all $g_i \in A \cup B$. The above situation is equivalent to $Y$ being invariant under $\langle A,B\rangle$.